# NodeJS, custom Content-Type gives empty body

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm having trouble using "application/vnd.api+json" as content type in NodeJS express app with bodyparser.

My app contains:

```
const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json({ type: 'application/vnd.api+json' }));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

Sending requests with header *"Content-Type: application/vnd.api+json"* and some json results in a empty req.body and undefined req.text.
Sending the same request with "*Content-Type: application/json"* works fine.

Also tried with `app.use(bodyParser.json({ type: 'application/*+json' }));`

Am i missing something?

Comment: You wrote "Content-Type: application/vnd.api+json" twice. What's the content type that works fine?

Comment: @neuhaus Sorry, should be application/json.